# SugarCRM webtolead form

Tags: forms, customization, sugarcrm

I'm having trouble setting up the webtolead form to work. I generated a webtolead form .html file inside SugarCRM CE edition Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082).

Then I put this .html file in the root of the SugarCRM (does it need to be there?)

After, I copied the contents of /modules/Campaigns/WebToLeadCapture.php, change the key (not sure where can I find this key or if I can choose whatever I like), the user and the user hash (found it in the database) and saved the new file as leadCapture_override.php I'm not sure if this file is supposed to stay in /modules/Campaigns/leadCapture_override.php or if it's supposed to be copied into the root directory of SugarCRM.

Then, I edited the .html file of the form to have this line:

<-form id="WebToLeadForm" action="http://mywebsite.com/index.php?entryPoint=leadCapture" method="POST" name="WebToLeadForm"->

Try all these but with no success. An error is showing saying: We're sorry, the server is currently unavailable, please try again later.

My server is up and running. What could be the problem? Can any of you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The server error you got is a very generic and unhelpful error message that is quite typical of Sugar and just leads you in the wrong direction.

However, I think you have misunderstood how Web to Lead works.  The HTML it generates it meant to be placed on your own website, likely outside of the Sugar webroot and probably even on another server.  You will want to add your own styles to the form, or better yet just extract the necessary HTML elements.  You should keep the POST URL as it is generated and any other hidden HTML inputs on the form.

The form data will then be posted to Sugar and will create a Lead linked to whichever Campaign you specified when creating the form.  The process is actually very simple as it is really just standard form submission.